# Incorrect JavaScript Parameters Syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, parameters

I'm trying to use JavaScript parameters in a function, but I'm not writing the syntax correctly.

This function is supposed to revert information in objects with the aa tag into whatever is specified with ba.

```
function myFunction(aa, ba){
    document.getElementById(aa).innerHTML = ba;
}
```

```
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(demo, My First Javascript)">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add single quotes around the inputs to your function:

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(aa, ba){
    document.getElementById(aa).innerHTML = ba;
}
```

html:

```
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('demo', 'My First Javascript')">Click Me!</button>
```

here's a link to a codepen.io demo:
https://codepen.io/167141162/pen/Vrgvbg

Answer (score 1):

[Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in JavaScript must be wrapped in either `""` or `''`. In your example, JavaScript will think that you are trying to pass a variable (or a function) called `demo` for the first argument, and the second one (`My First Javascript`) will throw a `SyntaxError`.

So, this will work:

```js
function myFunction(aa, ba){
    document.getElementById(aa).innerHTML = ba;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('demo', 'My First Javascript')">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your string parameters in single quotes

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('demo', 'My First Javascript')">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter << demo >> must be in single quotes, because in the js file the parameters take it as strings

`<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('demo', 'My First Javascript')">Click Me!</button>`

Comment: Why add the same answer as 3 people before you ?

Comment: I did not read the page update that said there are 2 new answers, I was still writing ... :sweat_smile: , and yes now it's really unuseful

Comment: @Enzo_Lizama This happened with my answer too (@Denno answered a few seconds before me), but the thing is that your answer 7 mins after the first answers, so I thought it was otherwise. Sorry.

Comment: I went to bring food after reading the question and then started writing: smile:, no problem